# Ant fails to build when using Google APIs

Tags: java, android, ant, build, google-api

I am trying to build my Android project with Ant. Whenever I use Eclipse to do the build the app compiles sucessfully. I am then able to run a `ant installd` and install the debug version of the app to my device. However if I run a `ant clean` and then run `ant debug` the build fails beccause it can not find the class OverlayItem. However in the project.properties I have `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:4`. What am I doing wrong?

**Console Output**

```
cas-v1500-sh:VIIAD Ant VIIAD$ ant debug
Buildfile: /Users/VIIAD/Desktop/VIIAD/VIIAD Ant/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Gathering info for VIIAD Ant...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 16
    [setup] Project Target: Google APIs
    [setup] Vendor: Google Inc.
    [setup] Platform Version: 1.6
    [setup] API level: 4
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] 

-build-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 42 source files to /Users/VIIAD/Desktop/VIIAD/VIIAD Ant/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/VIIAD/Desktop/VIIAD/VIIAD Ant/src/com/android/viiad/SearchResultsMapActivity.java:154: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class OverlayItem
    [javac] location: class com.android.viiad.SearchResultsMapActivity
    [javac]     public class SearchResultItemOverlay extends com.android.viiad.mapviewballoons.BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    [javac]                                                                                                           ^
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/Users/VIIAD/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:602: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/VIIAD/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:622: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it still perplexes me but I fixed the problem by replacing `OverlayItem` with `com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem` even thought I had the import `import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import `OverlayItem` into `com.android.viiad.SearchResultsMapActivity`?

`import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;`

Edit: Assuming you have all your imports in place, I would try [converting the Eclipse project to use Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454616/1101070).  Do make a backup of the original of course.

Comment: @Sbossb Did converting the Eclipse project to Ant make a difference?

Comment: Yes that is how I imported the project into Ant. I might need to include the maps.jar in addition to android.jar since my project requires the Google Maps API. I will see. If Eclipse does the build it works fine and Ant can do builds after Eclipse does it. However if I clean the project and try to build from just the source with Ant I get the error message.